# Uniqueness of $g$ on Riesz Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

**Theorem.** Suppose $1\le p < \infty$, $\mu$ is a $\sigma$- finite positive measure on $X$, and $\Phi$ is a bounded linear functional on $L^p(\mu)$. Then there is a unique $g\in L^q(\mu)$, where $q$ is the exponent conjugate to $p$, such that $$\Phi (f)=\int_X fg\;d\mu\quad\forall f\in L^p(\mu).\tag1$$ Moreover, if $\Phi$ and $g$ are related as in $(1)$, we have $$\lVert \Phi \rVert = \lVert g \rVert_q.$$

**Proof.** Uniqueness of $g$.

If $g$ and $g'$ satisfy $(1)$, then the integral of $g-g'$ over any measurable set $E$ of finite measure is $0$, and the $\sigma$- finiteness of $\mu$ implies therefore that $g-g'=0$ a.e.

We have that $0=\int_Xf(g-g')\;d\mu$ for every $f\in L^p$, thus in particular, $$0=\int_X\chi_E(g-g')\;d\mu=\int_E(g-g')\;d\mu\tag2$$ for every $E\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$. Since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite exists a sequence $\{E_n\}$ of disjoint sets such that $$X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\quad\text{and}\quad \mu(E_n)<\infty.$$    From $(2)$ we have that $$\int_X(g-g')\;d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{E_{n}} (g-g')\;d\mu=0$$

> ***Question***$$\int_X (g-g')\;d\mu\implies g=g' a.e$$

Comment: I think it would be better to reverse order: from (1) it and the last sentence it follows that integral of $g - g'$ over any set with finite measure is $0$, and by previous line it implies that $g - g' = 0$ a.e., so $g = g'$ in $L^q$ sense.

Comment: @mihaild I didn't understand what you mean, could you explain the details? Thank you

Comment: To prove that $g$ is uniq, assume we have some function $g'$ that also satisfies (1), and then prove that $g = g'$. You understand, why this works? and how we prove that $g = g'$?

Comment: @mihaild don't understand why we can conclude that g = g ', which theorem are we applying? Does the known result not refer to non-negative functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments, it seems like question is: why, if $\int_E (g - g')\, d\mu = 0$ for any set $E$ of finite measure, then $g = g'$ $\mu$-a.e.?

Note that $$\{x | g(x) \neq g'(x)\} = \bigcup_n \{x : g(x) - g'(x) > \frac{1}{n}\} \cup \bigcup_n \{x: g(x) - g'(x) < -\frac{1}{n}\}\tag2$$, so if all sets at the right side have measure $0$, then set at the left side has measure $0$ too, and so $g = g'$ a.e. (by definition).

Assume $A_n \{x : g(x) - g'(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}$ has non-zero measure for some $n$.

Then let $E$ be subset of it that has non-zero but finite measure. Such $E$ exists: as $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, $X = \cup_k X_k$ where $\mu(X_k) < \infty$. We then have $A_n = \cup_k (A_n \cap X_k)$, and as left side has positive measure, so does at least one set on the right side; however, as corresponding set is subset of $X_k$ for some $k$, it also has finite measure, and we can choose $E = A \cap X_k$.

We have $\int_E g(x) - g'(x)\, d\mu \geq \mu(E) \frac{1}{n} > 0$ - contradiction, so the set $A_n$ has measure $0$.

Case with $\{x : g(x) - g'(x) < -\frac{1}{n}\}$ is similar.

So, all sets at the right side of (2) have measure $0$.

Comment: Thanks! But who assures us that such a set $E$ exists?

Comment: It follows from $\sigma$-finitness, added to answer.